TDA2050 produces pulse on startup
When I turn the BTS6142D on I get a pulse on the output of the TDA amp. Below is first the schematic of the design. I removed the components from the other side of the transformer since nothing was connected there.

The scope output is shown below, the blue trace is the trace of the output of the amplifier after the electrolytic cap.

During normal operation the amp produces a square wave shown below:

Is there a way I can get rid of/reduce the initial pulse produced by the amplifier on initial startup that will not affect the normal operation behavior of the circuit?

What is signal? Also, maybe try without D5.

@Aaron sorry that is the signal injected by the micro, which is a PWM, the output is the amplified version of the "SIGNAL"

What does it do on power up?  Micros can have power up glitches on their I/O as well.

@Aaron the micro is powered up first, I then waited for 2 minutes before turning on the BTS. I also scoped that line disconnected from the amp and is was low the entire time.

Diodes have a capacitance when they are reverse biased.  D5 could be leaking current on power up.

Also, there is a voltage divider on the input of IN+.  Is the opamp outputing a DC level?  If so, that's going to charge C10 and cause what you are seeing.

@Aaron yes it is a voltage divider. What do you mean by DC level? The output is also shown in the post with reference to GND.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You removed components from after the transformer, but did you properly terminate the transformer?

@GodJihyo yes pin 3 was grounded only.

@JoeyB So no, it's not terminated then. Your amplifier is feeding the primary of a transformer with the secondary open, that's probably not a good idea. Those amps are meant to run into a 4 to 8 ohm load, so your transformer should match that to whatever your expected load impedance is, and for testing you should terminate the secondary with a resistor that mimics that expected load in both impedance and wattage. Also the resistor in your Zobel network is several orders of magnitude higher than that shown in the datasheet (4.7k vs 2.2Ω), is there a reason for that?

Your TDA2050 is an opamp, operated in single supply mode acc. to your schematic.
And you use (as Aaron mentionned) R17, R18 (and C14) to create an artifical ground at 12V away from positive and negative supply of TDA2050.
But C14 is 0V at switching on U6.
It (U at C14) rises in an e curve in about 100k / 2 * 100 nF * 5 = 25 ms.
R20 and R19 amplify UC14 by factor 11 -> so pin 1 after 25 ms it reaches 11 * 12 V = 132 V - no, you only have 24V power supply - something below 24 V, let's guess 22V is the output of TDA2050 at pin 1.
And then the output pin 1 stays forever at 22V!
At startup the pin 1 rises from 0 to 22V and stays there.
C19 will be charged to 22V --> this explains your DSO curve.
Is your schematic correct?
It would only work, if the signal pulls pin 3 down to around 1.1V DC (then the output would be 12.1V DC), but this DC voltage range at pin 3 is very limited:

2.2V - no AC signal (output at e. g. 22V)
0V DC - no AC signal (ouput at e. g. 2V)
1.5V would be too much, 0.5V too low, the output could not reach maximum power without going into clipping!

And there is an example circuit of a single mode application in the datasheet of TDA2050 at page 5 (Figure 2), they place this for a good reason into the data sheet.
There R1 and R2 form a virtual ground - the input signal is DC decoupled with C1.
The R5 and R4 needs also a DC decoupling - there because
a) the amplification factor is ca. 35
b) the offset voltage of TDA2050 can be 15 mV --> 35 * 15 mV = ca. 500 mV max offset at output pin 1 = not good (asymmetric --> distortion at high audio volume).
Therefore C4 is added, the pin 4 has only up to 15 mV DC offset.
And in the table the write at "C2" in column "LARGER" -->
Worse Turn-off Transient
Worse Turn-on Delay
There the transient pulse comes from. (your C14)
But your schematic would amplify AC only properly if signal pulls pin3 down to ca 1.1 V DC!
In the Figure 2 the input signal can have any DC level between Vs/2 .. 0V ... -3V ... (for safety better nearer to 0V or negative values than Vs/2).
PS: The pin numbers in your schematic does not fit the ones in the datasheet - is it another chip - can you provide the proper datasheet else?
Answers to Comments
The output pin of an ideal operational amplifier would reach 0V to 24V - the power supply. But the figure 3 of this [datasheet from STM for TDA2050] tells me that, this is not true - chapter "Limited Output Voltage" in the wikipedia article. So I guess 2 V for minimum and 22 V for maximum - in reality it could be 1V...3V... and ...21...23 V, the datasheet does not tell this (like e. g. "Output voltage swing" in chapter 6.5 of 741 datasheet)
Even if you power already R18, R17 ... with 24V - U over C14 will be 12 V (theoretically) - if "SIGNAL" is not connected.
The 12 V come from Kirchhoff's law.
What is your "SIGNAL"? A DC free AC signal?
Then the voltage at pin 3 will be 12 VDC (+ some AC from "SIGNAL").
The TDA2050 is configured as non-inverting amplifier with R19 and R20.
That means it amplifies the voltage between pin 3 and ground (because R20 is connected to ground) by factor 1 + R19 / R20 = 11. So 11 * 12 V = 132 V theoretically, but an opamp can't provide more than the supply voltage at the output - here 24 V supply. A rail to rail opamp could provide 24 V, here with TDA2050 I guess something like 22 V practically.
Measure DC voltage at pin 1 of TDA2050 It will be something between 20 V and 23 V.
Even if you apply a signal, the (DC) voltage at pin 3 will be 12 V (+ AC from signal).
Main Issue
Normally opamps/TDA2050 should be operated with dual supply +/-12V (V+ = +12V, V- = -12V) - and the power and signal ground are both the same in the middle at 0V.
But if you use a single supply of 24V (V+ = 24 V, V- = 0V), make a circuit, that the TDA2050 thinks he is operated in dual supply mode!
Therefore you have to create a signal ground by yourself at 12V. Like that you get "same" thing as with dual power supply - your 24V (V+) is +12V above signal ground and 0V (V-) is -12V related to signal ground (at 12 V in single power supply mode and 0V in dual power supply mode).
If you operate the TDA2050 with single supply mode, 0V is the negative power supply of TDA2050 - and you need a virtual ground, that is halfway between negative (0V) and positive (24V) power supply of TDA2050 - that is 12V. You create it with R18 and R17 - but R20 is connected to 0 V and not to that virtual/signal ground between R18 and R17!
You use the drawn ground symbol for the negative power supply, what can be confusing. There can be different grounds for different aims.
E. g. see Different grounds --> your ground symbol represents the (single) "power supply ground" of 0V.
But for the amplification of the signal the TDA2050/opamp needs a "signal ground" - that is the point where R18 and R17 meet - at 12 V - to that point R20 should be connected instead of "power supply ground". Then it will work "normal".
But I advise to use an example circuit coming from the datasheets, they are well thought and adaptable to your purposes/requirements.

I tried powering the R18 "OUT" net on first before turning on the BTS to supply the TDA. However I still get the pulse. I used a generic symbol from Kicad. Yes the pins do not match however I was using the +,- and power points for reference with the actual TDA pinout. I do not understand this "but this DC voltage range at pin 3 is very limited". How did you get the 2.2V, 0V and 1.5V and w

Also "0V DC - no AC signal (ouput at e. g. 2V)" how does a 0V DC at pin3 result in 2V at the output?

I edited answer - I think I got the clue, where you miss it. Even if you use a single power supply, you have to create a circuit, that the TDA2050 "thinks", it is operated in dual power mode - with signal ground half way between V+ and V- of TDA2050! In single power supply mode: V+ = 24 V, signal ground = 12 V, V- = 0V (power "ground", but not signal ground!) - in dual power supply mode: V+ = 12V, signal ground = 0V, V- = -12V ... and R20 has to be connected to (virtual) signal ground of 12 V between R18 and R17!

Thank you for still taking the time to answer. I will read through it and see if I understand it better now.

The only way is to first pull the non inverting input of the amp to ground during startup. Yes this produces a spike but it is far lower than the what I had before and it is also less harmful to the components downstream.
